# return values as arrays from PHP function

Tags: php, arrays, function

I am trying to return values as arrays but failing,

function call

```
$rates = getamount($Id, $days, $date, $code);
```

function

```
function getamount($Id, $days, $date, $code) {
    // fetch data from database
    // run whileloop
    while() {
        // Do other stuff
        // Last get final output values
        $rates['id'] = $finalid;
        $rates['days'] = $finaldays;
        // more and more
        $rates['amount'] = $finalamount;
        //If echo any variable here, can see all values of respective variable.
    }
    //If echo any variable here, can only see last value.
    return $rates;
}
```

And last outside the function (need this too so load variables into session also as arrays)

```
$compid = $rates['id'];
$totaldays = $rates['days'];
$totalamount = $rates['amount'];
```

Tried couple of solutions from SO but not able to get my head around this

Comment: how your while loop is set up, it will run infinitely until the script times out. You'll never get to the return.

Comment: that [while loop](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.while.php) doesn't look right

Comment: can't post the whole code, it's totally alright at my end,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Martin is right with his answer, I would just add some explanation.

In your `while` loop, you are overwriting the same array, so at the end, it will contain data of the last row from the database query results.

To fix that, you need an array of arrays. Each `$rate` array represents one row from the database, `$rates` is an array of those rows:

```
function getamount($Id, $days, $date, $code)
{
    // fetch data from database

    $rates = []; // initialize $rates as an empty array

    while (whatever) {
        $rate = []; // initialize $rate as an empty array

        // fill $rate with data
        $rate['id'] = $finalid;
        $rate['days'] = $finaldays;
        // more and more
        $rate['amount'] = $finalamount;

        // add $rate array at the end of $rates array
        $rates[] = $rate;
    }

    return $rates;
}
```

Now try to check what's inside the `$rates` array:

```
$rates = getamount($Id, $days, $date, $code);
var_dump($rates);
```

To get data out of `$rates` array, you need a loop again (the same way as you have created it):

```
foreach ($rates as $rate) {
    var_dump($rate);

    // now you can access is as you were trying it in your question
    $compid = $rate['id'];
    $totaldays = $rate['days'];
    $totalamount = $rate['amount'];
}
```

Comment: Great. Did you get the principle? I think if you check what's inside the `$rates` array (using `var_dump($rates)` it can help you to understand it.

Comment: yup, got it, what I was missing not initializing array inside array, thanks alot for clearing it

Comment: Great. You should **always** initialize an array, before using it (before adding items to it). You'll prevent unexpected results.

Answer (score 1):

Did you want to do something like:

```
function getamount($Id, $days, $date, $code) {
    $rates = [];
    while (whatever) {
        $rate = [];
        $rate['id'] = $finalid;
        $rate['days'] = $finaldays;
        // more and more
        $rate['amount'] = $finalamount;

        $rates[] = $rate;
    }

    return $rates;
}
```